# I can't use AlertDialog in onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-alertdialog

I try to use AlertDialog in onMessageReceived, but I have this error.

```
05-04 11:27:40.038 30721-31424/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
                                                                              Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 30721
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:108)
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:125)
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:967)
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:986)
                                                                                  at com.xxx.xxx.util.FirebaseMessagingService.optionalAlert(FirebaseMessagingService.java:78)
                                                                                  at com.xxx.xxx.util.FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(FirebaseMessagingService.java:38)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzl(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzJ(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String msg=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        String Valuekey = remoteMessage.getData().get("key");

        if (Valuekey.equals("true")) {
            optionalAlert();
        }else {
            Util.Alert(this,getString(R.string.ConsignmentNoFound));
        }

       // Util.Alert(getBaseContext(),msg);
    }

    private void optionalAlert () {


        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.ConsignmentFound));
        textView.setTextSize(24);
        adb.setCustomTitle(textView);


        //adb.setTitle(getString(R.string.ConsignmentFound));


        adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);


        adb.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(FirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
                nextActivity.putExtra("act", "PinValidate");
                startActivity(nextActivity);

            } });


        adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            } });
        adb.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show dialog in Receiver because Receive has different 'Context' which is not for showing any User Interface.

If you want to show Dialog then start an Activity which will have Dialog Theme.

Comment: Although this still applies, FirebaseMessagingService is a Service.

Answer (score 3):

> I know it's too late to replay but It may help someone. It's possible to show AlertDialog in FirebaseMessagingService. All you have
> to do is create an activity and set its theme as Dialog like below I
> have used theme for the activity at manifest file.

**Result**

[image]

**In Manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".View.StartCompaignDialogActivity"
    android:label="Start Compaign!"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"></activity>
```

**StartCompaignDialogActivity.java**

```
public class StartCompaignDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Dialog dialog;
    Button yes,no;
    String TAG = "StartCompaignDialogActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_compaign);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_start_compaign_dialog,null);
        builder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        yes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start_compaign_yes);
        no = (Button)view. findViewById(R.id.start_compaign_no);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        no.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.start_compaign_yes){
            Log.e(TAG,"customer press yes.");

        }else if (v.getId() == R.id.start_compaign_no){
            Log.e(TAG,"customer press no.");
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_start_compaign_dialog.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context=".View.StartCompaignDialogActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#c5282828"
                android:text="Start Compaign!"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sanomat_regular"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/h5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#87000000"
                android:text="Ambassador is waiting for your compaign to start. Do you want to start your compaign ?"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sanomat_regular"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/start_compaign_yes"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/yes"
                    android:textColor="#f5f1f1f1"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:text="YES"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sanomat_bold"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/start_compaign_no"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/no"
                    android:textColor="#f5f1f1f1"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:text="No"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sanomat_bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Here is the code where you want to show alert dialog. Just start the activity inside onMessageReceived method. Alertdialog will appear to the user.

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirebaseMessage.this,StartCompaignDialogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Hi, why are you setting the layout twice? 1) setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_compaign_dialog); 2) builder.setView(view); ?

Comment: builder.setView attaching view with AlerDialog whereas setContentView is attaching view/layout with activity

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, layout file name is separte for activity. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

this works for sure

```
package pkg.name

import pkg.name.DisplayAlert
import android.content.Intent
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
class CloudMsg:  FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {}

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val mDisplayAlert = Intent(this, DisplayAlert::class.java)
        mDisplayAlert.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        mDisplayAlert.putExtra("title",  remoteMessage.notification?.title)
        mDisplayAlert.putExtra("body",  remoteMessage.notification?.body)
        startActivity(mDisplayAlert)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {}

}

package pkg.name

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class DisplayAlert : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal var title: String? = null
    internal var body: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        b = intent.extras
        if (b != null) {
            title = b!!.getString("title")
            body = b!!.getString("body")
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle(title)
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.store)
            builder.setMessage(body)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, id ->
                    finish()
                }
            val alertDialog = builder.create()
            alertDialog.show()
        }
    }
    companion object {
        var b: Bundle? = null
    }
}

<service
    android:name=".CloudMsg"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<activity
    android:name=".DisplayAlert"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Total_Translucent">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<style name="Total_Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

 <color name="transparent">@android:color/transparent</color>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform operations that affect UI on a specific thread. Given the activity instance, you have access to a handy method to do just that:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // perform ui operations...
    }
});
```

Comment: where I can implement this ? in the class FirebaseMessagingService on in the actual activity?

Comment: Get an instance of the current running activity.

Answer (score -1):

In your MyFirebaseMessagingService class:-

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{

        context = this;
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message getMessageId: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message getMessage: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message getAction: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("action"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message template_id: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("template_id"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message notification_user_id: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_user_id"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message joined_user_id: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_id"));

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"), remoteMessage.getData().get("action"),
                remoteMessage.getData().get("template_id"),
                remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_user_id"),
                remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_id"));
    }

private void sendNotification(final String messageBody, String messageAction, String templateId, String notiUserId, String sender_id) {
            if (ApplicationClass.getInstance().getCurrentClass() != null) {
                //Let this be the code in your n'th level thread from main UI thread
                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Common.displayAlert(ApplicationClass.getInstance().getCurrentClass(), messageBody);
                    }
                });
            }

}
```

And In Common Class make a Method to display a Dialog;-

```
 public static void displayAlert(final Context context, String respMsg) {
        try {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent splashIntent = new Intent(context, MobileNoVerificationActivity.class);
                    splashIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(splashIntent);
                }
            });
            builder.setTitle("" + context.getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage(respMsg);
            builder.create().show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you